# this error" Err_TOO_Many_Redirect" path is admin/noroute/denide?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, admin, login, redirect

[image]

this erro happend when user role change to denied.and whenwver you loggin to admin page it is redirect many times error.

Answer (score 0):

This error happens because of admin role permission denied for all.so change permission with help of database all permission allowed.